# Software Updater shows unmet dependencies error

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I have had Ubuntu 22.04 running on my laptop since Dec 2022 with no problems until now. This morning I saw the Software Updater notification with the statement

```
An error occurred, please run package manager...

The error message was:Error marking the upgrade (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver:Resolve generated breaks,this may be caused by held packages

This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies
```

Having no luck in trying to fix this, I simply restored from a system backup image from a few months ago. When I rebooted the same notification error message appeared despite the fact that I restored from a Ubuntu system that was working fine.

Running

```
sudo apt update
```

revealed some details about a problem with the skypeforlinux package:

```
289 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

So I removed the ppa and I was able to

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

After reboot, the notification of pkgProblemResolver still reappeared. I then removed skypeforlinux completely and I still get this notification.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Why does this appear in an old backup restore which was working fine previously?

EDIT: While waiting, the notification error disappeared! I have no idea why this happened, but it appears resolved. If someone can provide info that would be helpful. Was there an error introduced by the persons responsible for managing the packages?

Comment: As the original error noted, might be caused by "phasing" the availability of the packages for upgrade (meaning some percentage is held back).  Search this site for phasing, and see the ways to force the upgrade, but I usually just wait a day or two.

Comment: "*289 packages can be upgraded*" suggests a serious problem that you were perhaps unaware of.

Comment: It was 289 packages because I restored from a system backup from a few months ago. So lots to upgrade to catch up. The subject of "phased updates" is new to me, something to learn. I should say though that I did not request the upgrade. Software Updater was doing it automatically in the background and it got blocked by the held packages. I responded too quickly and I guess I should have been patient and waited a bit for the error message to go away.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/2030262